# I am using google autocompete address suggestion for my project, now i want to show address suggestion only for australia?

Tags: php, jquery, google-maps, google-api

I am using google autocompete address suggestion for my project.  Now I want to show address suggestions only for Australia. Other countries' addresses should not be displayed in the google address suggestion.

My code snippet:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="searchtxt" id="searchtxt" onFocus="initaddress('searchtxt')">
```

SCRIPT:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>
<script src="<?php echo BASE_URL;?>media/user/js/map/map_autoload_lonlag.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  function initialize() {  
        var input = document.getElementById('searchtxt');
        var options = {
            types: ['regions'],
            componentRestrictions: {country: 'au'}
        }; 
        clearResults();
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
   }

  $(document).ready(function(){
     initialize();
  });
</script>
```

Please suggest what I need to change.

Comment: Please tell us the output you are receiving with this code and why the output is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see below link may be help ful

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Place Autocomplete Restricted to Multiple Countries</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
   * element that contains the map. */
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
  /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #description {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
  }

  #infowindow-content .title {
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  #infowindow-content {
    display: none;
  }

  #map #infowindow-content {
    display: inline;
  }

  .pac-card {
    margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
    border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: Roboto;
  }

  #pac-container {
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    margin-right: 12px;
  }

  .pac-controls {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 11px;
  }

  .pac-controls label {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 300;
  }

  #pac-input {
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-left: 12px;
    padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 400px;
  }

  #pac-input:focus {
    border-color: #4d90fe;
  }

  #title {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #4d90fe;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 6px 12px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="pac-card" id="pac-card">
  <div>
    <div id="title">
      Countries
    </div>
    <div id="country-selector" class="pac-controls">
      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changecountry-usa">
      <label for="changecountry-usa">USA</label>

      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changecountry-usa-and-uot" checked="checked">
      <label for="changecountry-usa-and-uot">USA and unincorporated organized territories</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="pac-container">
    <input id="pac-input" type="text"
        placeholder="Enter a location">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="infowindow-content">
  <img src="" width="16" height="16" id="place-icon">
  <span id="place-name"  class="title"></span><br>
  <span id="place-address"></span>
</div>

<script>
  // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
  // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
  // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: 50.064192, lng: -130.605469},
      zoom: 3
    });
    var card = document.getElementById('pac-card');
    var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
    var countries = document.getElementById('country-selector');

    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(card);

    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

    // Set initial restrict to the greater list of countries.
    autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions(
        {'country': ['us', 'pr', 'vi', 'gu', 'mp']});

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var infowindowContent = document.getElementById('infowindow-content');
    infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
    });

    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
      infowindow.close();
      marker.setVisible(false);
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      if (!place.geometry) {
        // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
        // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
        window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
        return;
      }

      // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
        map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
      }
      marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
      marker.setVisible(true);

      var address = '';
      if (place.address_components) {
        address = [
          (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
          (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
          (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
        ].join(' ');
      }

      infowindowContent.children['place-icon'].src = place.icon;
      infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = place.name;
      infowindowContent.children['place-address'].textContent = address;
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

    // Sets a listener on a given radio button. The radio buttons specify
    // the countries used to restrict the autocomplete search.
    function setupClickListener(id, countries) {
      var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
      radioButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({'country': countries});
      });
    }

    setupClickListener('changecountry-usa', 'us');
    setupClickListener(
        'changecountry-usa-and-uot', ['us', 'pr', 'vi', 'gu', 'mp']);
  }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>

</body>
</html>
```